# Strange behaviour of NSAttributedString in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

When I checked with iOS 6, I can change text size of a UITextView (not a text field) by adding attributes without any issues.  (By changing UITextView's attributedText property)

For eg:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
```

If I have above text in a UITextView, I can increase the size of the text portion of `BBBB` without it overlapping `AAAA` in iOS 6. BBBB text would increase it's size to the down side direction. Even if I increase the size of `AAAA` it would increase it's size towards `BBBB` but it would pushes `BBBB` text towards down to get space.

But when I run the same code in iOS 8, whenever I increase the size, `BBBB` part overlaps `AAAA`. Because in iOS 8, BBBB would change it's size to the up side direction so it overlaps AAAA text.

Is this a bug in iOS or is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had set `paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight` property to the size of Font size. Removing that line did the trick.